# FLASH/ANIMATE APIInternalError

Tags: ios, flash, air, jquery-animate

I am trying to export an app I made in Adobe Flash/Animate but whenever I try to export I get the error message: "Nick's iPhone: The device has encountered an unexpected error. Installation Error: APIInternalError."

This happens when I try to use an app I've been working on for months and a fresh version with no code, though also using the same credentials.

I've updated my iPhone to the newest iOS and I am concerned that the jump to 64 has made exporting from Flash impossible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure it's useful for others to include your phone's name in the title?

Comment: Oops, thought I had deleted that.

Comment: Exporting apps from Animate is certainly still possible. Installation Errors are usually due to certificate or provisioning profile issues.

My advise would be to delete all your certificates and profiles and recreate them from scratch.